# ¿Como puedo hacer un update de un arreglo de datos de una etiqueta select html en PHP y MySql?

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, pdo, update

Buenos a todos y como dice la pregunta lo que busco es hacer un update por id de un array de valores de PHP a MySql, por lo que estuve investigando una de las maneras mas sencillas de hacerlo es recorrer cada uno de los valores con un forEach y fuera del forEach hacer el update.

Adjunto mi codigo con el cual estoy llevando a cabo esta operacion:
Lo primero que hago es llamar a mi base de datos y seguido hago una validación en la cual verifico que he recibido el id correctamente y lo almaceno en una variable, seguido de eso hago un select en el cual muestro los datos de mi base de datos por ID.

```
<?php
require_once "../connection/conexion.php";
if (isset($_GET['id_usuario'])) {
 $id = $_GET['id_usuario'];
 $result2 = $cnn->prepare("SELECT * FROM productos WHERE id_usuario = ?");
  $result2->execute(array($id)); 
?>
```

Seguido de esto hago un forEach de result2, hay mismo ingreso el select y agrego en el name que va hacer un arreglo en cual seria estatus[]

```
      <table class="w-full">
                <tr class="p-1 shadow-sm h-10 border-b border-gray-200">
                  <th>Cantidad</th>
                  <th>Unidad</th>
                  <th>Descripcion</th>
                  <th>Aceptado/Rechazado</th>
                </tr>
                <?php foreach ($result2 as $key) { ?>
                  <tr class="text-center h-10 p-2 divide-y divide-gray-200">
                    <td><?php echo $key["cantidad"] ?> </td>
                    <td><?php echo $key["unidad"] ?> </td>
                    <td><?php echo $key["descripcion"] ?> </td>
                    <td>
                        <select class="outline-none text-center" name="estatus[]" id="estatus">
                          <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
                          <option value="aceptado">Aceptado</option>
                          <option value="rechazado">Rechazado</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                <?php } ?>
              </table>
          <div class="flex w-full my-6">
            <div class="mx-10">
              <button class="border-1 border-green-500 w-24 h-10 font-semibold hover:bg-green-500 hover:border-none hover:text-white" name="actualizar" type="submit">Modificar</button>
            </div>
            <div class="mx-12 marginT">
              <a class="link" href="./proveedor.php">Back</a>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Obtengo la siguiente interfaz:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces una vez que el usuario selecciona una opcion ya sea que el valor sea rechazado o aceptado al darle al boton modificar con el siguiente codigo obtengo los valores de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo donde capturo los datos:

```
 if (isset($_POST['actualizar'])) {
    $estado = $_POST['estatus'];
}
```

Si hago un var_dump obtengo lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora bien aquí es donde trato de hacer un update en el cual dependiendo los valores estos se almacenaran en cada una de las columnas que tienen los valores cantidad unidad y descripcion y como comentaba en un inicio por lo que investigue una de las formas es haciendo el foreach del arreglo que obtuve, guardo los datos en una variable y fuera del forEach procedo a realizar dicho update.

```
 if (isset($_POST['actualizar'])) {
    $estado = $_POST['estatus'];
    $consulta = $cnn->prepare("UPDATE productos SET estatus = :estatus WHERE id_usuario = :$id");

    foreach ($estado as $key => $val) {
      $estado = $val;
    }

    $consulta->bindParam(':estatus', $estado);

    try {
      $consulta->execute();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
      die("Error: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br>on line: " . $e->getLine() . "<br>on file: " . $e->getFile());
    }
}
```

pero el error que obtengo es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Algo que me gustaría agregar y en caso que igual tenga algo que ver, es que estas son mis dos tablas de BD en las que estoy trabajando:

La tabla **Usuario** donde solo ingresa sus datos y en el cual id_usuario será compartido con la tabla productos, en la cual por medio de `$lastInsertId();` obtengo el id y se lo almaceno al id_usuario que cree en productos, aclaro eso porque no estoy usando llaves foráneas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La tabla **Productos** donde el usuario almacena la cantidad descripción y unidad en este caso ingreso números para que sea un poco mas cómodo de visualizar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien puede ayudarme con este problema o conoce alguna otra forma de realizar dicho Update se los aceptaría con mucho gusto.

***Actualización***

Quitando el $ del id y pasandolo en un binParam pude insertar de manera casi correcta los valores del arreglo con el unico detalle que ahora solo me inserta el ultimo valor

```
 if (isset($_POST['actualizar'])) {
    $estado = $_POST['estatus'];

    foreach ($estado as $key) {
      $consulta = $cnn->prepare("UPDATE productos SET estatus = :estatus WHERE id_usuario = :id");
      $estatus = $val;
      $lastId = $key;
      $consulta->bindParam(':estatus', $estatus);
      $consulta->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
      $consulta->execute();
    }
```

Con esto bajo mi lógica fue que si el estatus que contiene $val tiene los 3 valores entonces solo tendria que meter el binParam en el forEach pero veo que ni aun asi me respeta el ciclo con esto que podria hacer para que dicho ciclo me respete o si algo esta mal dentro de mi codigo o logica que estoy implementando

Aquí una imagen de que me inserta el ultimo valor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El error es fácil, te está diciendo que no coincide el número de parámetros en tu **bind_param** con tu sentencia, le estas pasando dos parámetros, luego ```SET estatus = :estatus WHERE id_usuario = :id``` quita el **$** a $:id ,luego después del bindParam que ya tienes añades esta línea: ```$consulta->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);```

Comment: Tienes varios errores de concepto y de código por arreglar: 1) No estas recogiendo los ids de los productos que quieres actualizar, solo los estatus 2) Dentro del foreach estas sobreescribiendo todo el rato la misma variable, por lo tanto tan solo quedara un valor al final y el resto no habran servido para nada 3) En la consulta usas `:$id` que no tienes ni predefinido antes y ademas, si lo pusieras bien `:id` te faltaria su `bindParam` (ese es el error que te da)  4) el Update lo haras igual en todos los productos del mismo usuario y no creo que quieras eso

Comment: Cuando hayas repasado todo eso, si sigues teniendo problemas, pulsa sobre [edit] en el pie de la pregunta actualizándola con el nuevo código y lo volvemos a analizar

Comment: Con respecto al punto 4 la variable ```$estado = $val``` si contiene los datos de los 3 select, entonces  en efecto como me comentabas quitando el **$** del id me inserta pero solo el ultimo valor, entonces  ¿como podría solucionar que el ciclo sea respetado y me inserte cada uno de los valores?

Comment: Pues poniendolo todo dentro del ciclo, es decir, el `bindParam` y el `try` entero tambien.  Fíjate que sigues creyendo que $estado = $val contiene los datos de los 3 select, pero no es cierto, pues en cada ciclo la estas sobreescribiendo, y al final prevalece el valor del último ciclo, que es lo que dices que está ocurriendo.

Comment: Tu problema ahora es mi punto 4 de nuevo, pues haces esto: `"UPDATE productos SET estatus = :estatus WHERE id_usuario = :id"` lo que quiere decir que cada vez que la ejecutas dentro del ciclo estas cambiando TODOS los productos de ese usuario, y no los concretos que deberian ser en cada ciclo. Mirate mi punto 1 tambien.

Comment: Bueno efectivamente después de realizar bien las observaciones que me proporcionaste es verdad, el id_usuario que le estoy pasando en el update siempre es 1 entonces solo la posicion 1 de ese dato se actualizara para todos los valores, logre solucionarlo y corrígeme si me equivoco y es que agregue la posición de cada producto como id y eso lo lo puse en el ```WHERE id = id;``` con esto ya me permite al recoger el arreglo del select relacionar la posición de cada uno y actualizarlo con los valores correspondientes

Comment: Si la tabla `productos` tiene una clave primaria con solo el `id`, entonces si, ahora has hecho lo correcto... No te hace falta saber el usuario, solo el producto. Pero si no fuera así, es decir, que tuviera una clave compuesta por `id` + `id_usuario` donde el `id` se pudiera repetir, estariamos otra vez con el mismo problema, pero ahora actualizarias solo los mismos `id` que estuvieran compartidos por distintos usuarios.  Debes entender que cuando haces un UPDATE con solo un campo en el WHERE, si este se repite en la tabla, entonces estas actualizando **todos** los registros donde este repe.

Comment: Por eso insistía en el tema del UPDATE, porque veía que el `id_usuario` **sí** se repetia en varios registros, aunque desconocía si te pasaba lo mismo con el `id` del producto, y por eso te indicaba que tenías que pasárselo también (que es lo que te ha propuesto @DBE en su respuesta).  Pero si el `id` del producto no se repite entonces no te hace falta conseguir ambos datos, con el del producto es suficiente.

Comment: @masterguru estoy totalmente de acuerdo con tus comentarios, por eso puse en mi respuesta el **id_producto** y **id_usuario**, para que sea fácil el cambio. Aunque ahora vi en el comentario, que el **id_usuario** es siempre **1**, entonces con ```where id = :id_producto``` es suficiente.

Comment: Pues yo creo que si retocas tu respuesta con eso el OP deberia aceptártela y así cerramos esta pregunta correctamente.  Aún así, dudo que el id_usuario sea siempre 1, se habrá expresado mal, sino no tendria sentido tener esa columna. Aquí lo importante es que el id del producto sea único para poder hacer el UPDATE correctamente desde el formulario. Luego ya se preocupará de mejorar  la consulta agregando el id del usuario que seguramente podrá conseguir de alguna variable de sesión, para tener la certeza que un usuario no accede a productos de otro jugando con el código.

Comment: @masterguru he dejado un apartado **edit** con dichos cambios. Respecto a que el usuario será siempre 1 también lo dudo, estoy de acuerdo con tu comentario, por eso realmente conteste por lógica. Pero al menos sabe cómo hacerlo de una forma o de otra. Un saludo amigo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aparte de los comentarios, esta línea tengo que recordar, que te va actualizar el estado de todos los productos con id_usuario 1, y no creo que deseas eso, sino que te actualice por id_usuario y id_producto.

`$consulta = $cnn->prepare("UPDATE productos SET estatus = :estatus WHERE id_usuario = :id");`

Entonces si quieres actualizar solo el producto que selecciono dicho usuario con X ID, deberías añadir **id = :id_product**, quedaría así:

`$consulta = $cnn->prepare("UPDATE productos SET estatus = :estatus WHERE id = :id_product AND id_usuario = :id");`

Ahora veamos cómo se podría obtener el id_producto, en mi ejemplo uso un simple **checkbox**.

Es importante pasar el valor del **id_product** como clave [id], así tendremos siempre relación con el estado, imagínate que solo quieres cambiar el estado del producto con id 1 y 3, en este caso podrías tener problema, ya que no van a coincidir las claves.

Ahora sabiendo esto, esta parte de tu código quedaría así:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="id_producto[1]" value="1">

<select name="estatus[1]">
  <option value="0">selecciona</option>
  <option value="aceptado">Activado</option>
  <option value="rechazado">Rechazado</option>
</select>
```

Recuerda el valor 1 seria id_producto: 1, en tu código seria `name="id_producto[$id_producto] value="$id_producto"` y `name="estatus[$id_producto] value="$id_producto"`

También estas implementando mal tu *foreach*, aparte este sobre escribiendo a *$estado* en tu ciclo la que intentas recorrer:

```
foreach ($estado as $key => $val) {
      $estado = $val;
}

$consulta->bindParam(':estatus', $estado);
```

Deberías cambiar el nombre de *$estado = $val;* y añadir tu **$consulta** dentro de tu **foreach**.

```
  // Consulta (no hace falta en tu foreach)
  $consulta = $cnn->prepare("UPDATE productos SET estatus = :estatus WHERE id = :id_producto AND id_usuario = :id_usuario");

  foreach ($estado as $key => $val) {
      // $estado = $val;
      $estatus = $val;
      etc..

      // Bind parametros
      $consulta->bindParam(':estatus', $estatus, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $consulta->bindParam(':id_producto', $id_producto, PDO::PARAM_INT);
      $consulta->bindParam(':id_usuario', $id_usuario, PDO::PARAM_INT);
      // Ejecutar consulta ¡importante en tu foreach!
      $consulta->execute();
   }
```

Veamos como quedaría entonces todo lo comentado.

**Ejemplo:**

```
if (isset($_POST['actualizar'])) {
  // Obtenemos datos formulario
  //
  // Estado es un arreglo
  $estado = $_POST['estatus'] ?? '';
  // Product_id es un arregalo
  $product_id = $_POST['id_producto'] ?? '';
  // Pongo el Usuario manual
  $id_usuario = (int) 1;

  // Datos formulario son verdadero, te evitare problemas
  if ($estado && $product_id && $id_usuario) :

    try { 

      // Consulta (no hace falta que valla en tu foreach)
      $consulta = $cnn->prepare("UPDATE productos SET estatus = :estatus WHERE id = :id_producto AND id_usuario = :id_usuario");

      // Recorres los estados del formulario
      foreach ($estado as $key => $val) {
        
        // Obtenemos valor del estado
        $estatus = $val;

        // Comprobamos que el estado no sea 0, asi te evitas errores con claves etc
        if ($estatus != 0) :

          // Comprobamos que la clave coincida
          if (array_key_exists($key, $product_id))  $id_producto = $product_id[$key]; // Obtienes valor id producto que tiene relacion la clave con estatus :)    
          
          // Bind parametros
          $consulta->bindParam(':estatus', $estatus, PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $consulta->bindParam(':id_producto', $id_producto, PDO::PARAM_INT);
          $consulta->bindParam(':id_usuario', $id_usuario, PDO::PARAM_INT);
          // Ejecutar consulta
          $consulta->execute();

          if ($consulta) {
            $msg = 'Se guardo';
          } else {
            $msg = 'Problemas';
          }

        endif;     
      }
      
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
      die("Error: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br>on line: " . $e->getLine() . "<br>on file: " . $e->getFile());
    }

  else :
    $msg = 'El formulario esta vacio';
  endif;
}
```

**Edit:**

Ahora después del comentario de **@masterguru** vi que el *id* del *usuario* va a ser siempre **1**, entonces la modificación es fácil.

Veamos primera la sentencia y luego ya el código completo que simplemente hay que eliminar un par de líneas:

`$consulta = $cnn->prepare("UPDATE productos SET estatus = :estatus WHERE id = :id_producto");`

**El código completo adaptado:**

```
if (isset($_POST['actualizar'])) {
  
  // Estado es un arreglo
  $estado = $_POST['estatus'] ?? '';
  // Product_id es un arregalo
  $product_id = $_POST['id_producto'] ?? '';
   
  // Datos son verdadero
  if ($estado && $product_id) :

    try { 

      // Consulta (no hace falta que se repita)
      $consulta = $cnn->prepare("UPDATE productos SET estatus = :estatus WHERE id = :id_producto");

      // Recorres los estados que se han selecionado
      foreach ($estado as $key => $val) {
        
        // Obtenemos valor del estado
        $estatus = $val;

        // Comprobamos que el estado no sea 0, asi te evitas errores
        if ($estatus != 0) :

          // Comprobamos que la clave coincida
          if (array_key_exists($key, $product_id))  $id_producto = $product_id[$key]; // Obtienes valor id producto que tiene relacion la clave con estatus :)    
          
          // Bind parametros
          $consulta->bindParam(':estatus', $estatus, PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $consulta->bindParam(':id_producto', $id_producto, PDO::PARAM_INT);
          
          // Ejecutar
          $consulta->execute();

          if ($consulta) {
            $msg = 'Se guardo';
          } else {
            $msg = 'Problemas';
          }

        endif;     
      }
      
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
      die("Error: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br>on line: " . $e->getLine() . "<br>on file: " . $e->getFile());
    }

  else :
    $msg = 'El formulario esta vacio';
  endif;
}
```